# Plotting with matplotlib within an object function

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I have an object named `Map` and I want to call its method `showBasemap()`.

Map object

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
    from datetime import datetime

    class Map(object):

        def __init__(self,data,sites):
            self.data = data
            self.sites = sites
            self.cmap = None
            self.vmin = None
            self.vmax = None
            print("UPDATE: Map object created with current data")

        def setupBasemap(self):
            baseMap = Basemap(projection='mill',lon_0=180)
            # plot coastlines, draw label meridians and parallels.
            baseMap.drawcoastlines()
            baseMap.drawparallels(np.arange(-90,90,30),labels=[1,0,0,0])
            baseMap.drawmeridians(np.arange(baseMap.lonmin,baseMap.lonmax+30,60),labels=[0,0,0,1])
            # fill continents 'coral' (with zorder=0), color wet areas 'aqua'
            baseMap.drawmapboundary(fill_color='aqua')
            baseMap.fillcontinents(color='coral',lake_color='aqua')
            # shade the night areas, with alpha transparency so the
            # map shows through. Use current time in UTC.
            date = datetime.utcnow()
            CS=baseMap.nightshade(date)
            plt.title('Day/Night Map for %s (UTC)' % date.strftime("%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S"))
            plt.show()
            print("UPDATE: Basemap Setup...")
```

main.py

```
    from Map import *
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    def main():
        try:
            sites = []
            weather = [2,2,2]
            map = Map(weather,sites)
            map.setupBasemap()

    except IndexError:
        fmt = 'invalid file name'
        print(fmt.format(__file__.split('/')[-1]))

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

I have restructured my original post. I hope this clears things up... I cannot get any plt to show if I call an object function with plt functionality within. I copied the code from within the method into a test.py file and it works perfectly. I am confused as to why the plotting does not work the way I have it layed out.

Comment: A function or method needs to be defined using `def`. Apart, you need to show a [mcve] of the issue.

Comment: So does the partial code you show work or not, i.e. does calling the method the way you present it show the plot or not? The code itself looks reasonable, but if you have a problem running it, you need to show a [mcve] of the issue. In any case you do not need any threading.

Comment: There *should* not be any difference, unless you have something that is not shown here which prevents the code from running as usual. Just as with any other code problem, without a [mcve] (i.e. a code that someone else can copy, paste and run) this will probably not get solved. Such questions will eventually get closed with the reason *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself."*

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I have edited my question and made it layed out exactly the same as I have it.

Comment: I can run this example without problem (apart from the `except` being wrongly indented).

Comment: Any idea why my plot isn't showing up? Thank Stack Overflow for messing up my indentions...

Comment: (SO does not mess up code; copy your code from an editor, select it, press Ctrl+k, that's all.) If you want ideas on why this does not work as expected you may share *how*  you run this code and what system, versions etc are in use. Also, is this specific to basemap, or would just any code with plt.show() not show a window?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Neither. Like I said before If I copy the function setupBasemap into a separate file and run it as a standalone function it works perfectly. Only in this implementation is plt.show() not working.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. If it does not depend on the use of basemap, why is basemap used in the code at all?